# Push notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging for Web apps (JavaScript)

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello everyone I have a question about React native notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). If I use FCM with web app configuration (JavaScript). Will it work on iOS devices ?

Answer (score 0):

No, FCM only handle Push Notification on Android,

You need to use the APNS (Apple Push Notification service) to send a Push Notif to an IOS device.

If you have Expo, you can use a built-in service that will handle both platform for you.